# Understanding how ffmpeg's silenceremove filter correlates to Adobe Audition

Tags: adobe-audition, strip-silence, ffmpeg

I have a bunch of audio files (more than 4000) that I want to trim the leading and trailing silence from, that's where ffmpeg comes in.

For instance in the image bellow, the command I'm using is

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -af silenceremove=1:0:-63.563dB:1:0:-63.563dB output.mp3
```

[image]

From the command, -63.563dB is just the level high enough that doesn't remove the second burst of sound (marked with red). If I put -63.564dB, for instance, that part is removed. I found that number by trial and error, because ffmpeg's help command wasn't very helpful in that sense.

So, my question is how does that number (-63.563dB) relate to the markers on the vertical ruler on Adobe Audition? And what else can I put in so that it only remove leading and trailing silences, and very short burst of sound (no more that 0.01 ms)

Answer (score 1):

I've never used ffmpeg like this, but I had a quick squint at the [filter docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html), specifically the [`silenceremover`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#silenceremove) and straight away I noticed the detection system defaults to RMS. Maybe this is where the confusion about the dB value has come from. Try switching it to `peak`. It should work more the way you want, but I'm not sure if that would be better or not for you.

Comment: I'll try the peak parameter then. I'll also tried silenceremove=1:0.02:-50dB:1:0.02:-50dB, if I understood correctly that would give me enough room to remove bursts of that have a higher amplitude but that have a short duration (no more than 20 ms). It din't work that way either, the second burst of sound (which is about 150 ms long) was stripped away.

Comment: Yes, that seems like it should work(with `peak`), as RMS is an average measurement, it would have also been affecting the duration detection too. Let me know how it goes.